# How to lock siblings to prevent race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mutex, race-condition

Models:

```
Class Checklist
  has_many :checklist_items
end
```

```
Class ChecklistItem
  belongs_to :checklist

  after_save :update_checklist_completion

  def update_checklist_completion
    if siblings.unchecked.any?
      checklist.update(completed: false)
    else
      checklist.update(completed: true)
    end
  end
end
```

When a checklist item is saved it runs `update_checklist_completion` - if all the other checklist items on the checklist are also completed then it will update the checklist to be completed. The problem is if the checklist items are completed too quickly then when the method is run on the last checklist item, previous checklist items have not finished being updated, so it fails to mark the checklist as completed.

I believe this is a race condition. My thinking is it would be best to prevent the siblings from being updated while `update_checklist_completion` is being executed but unsure of the best way to achieve this. I've looked at `Mutex` but this seems to prevent the method from being accessed on that object. In my case I think I need to stop other objects (the siblings) from being updated

Comment: You should start with the guides article on which gives an overview and then read the docs for [optimistic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and [pessimistic locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) to see which is suited for your use case. Mutex is kind of irrelevant as what you want are database level locks.

Comment: Also one way to avoid to avoid the race condition is to not have that boolean attribute and instead determine if a check list is completed by counting the related records in the `checklist_items` join table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably callbacks, and especially non-database callbacks are not so good for this purpose

You can lock all that records if needed (parent and all children). Then inside opened transaction save child record, check other children and update parent

Something like this:

```rb
checklist.with_lock do
  checklist.checklist_items.lock!
  checklist_item.save!
  
  completed = !checklist.checklist_items.unchecked.exists?

  checklist.update!(completed:)
end
```

NB: if you apply different locks order in different places, deadlock will appear